# CSS - Display: Inline-block issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to debug a display problem shown below:
Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="pw_brand_product_list"><div class="wb-posted_in">Brand:</div><a href="https://www.google.com">My First Brand</a></span>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
 .wb-posted_in {display:inline-block; margin:5px}
```

When I put all this into JSFiddle, it shows properly "Brand: My First Brand" however, when I actually implement this onto my website, it doesn't seem to display properly it still shows as:

Brand:

My First Brand

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm assuming it's some very beginners mistake? I even tried to use !important and it still doesn't apply correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious or flagged by filter systems; users may not be able to visit them. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Considering that it works on JSFiddle, its most likely some other css on the site. Use a developer tool, like [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to inspect the element and see what styles are applied.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as I often complain, the questioner posted a link to his web site as an example of his markup problem. Then, when he solved his problem, he deleted his link and left his question useless and pointless as well as the answer is now useless and pointless. His posted markup does not show the problem. All questions are to have a complete example that shows the problem here, not a web site, a jsfiddle, or any other third party site! [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took a look at the page you linked. It seems that `.wb-posted_in` has a `width: 100%`. Changing this with `width: auto` seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly! So much to learn :)

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions. He did not post here the required example markup that reproduces the problem. Once he had your answer, based on his web site alone, he deleted that link which makes your answer of no value and his question of no use to anyone ever again. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow and answering such questions is a disservice. Not all questions can or should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Please don't do that again.